# Trying to get number of days in specific month using Calendar object

Tags: java, calendar

I'm trying to write a `Calendar` in java that outputs an `html` web page with a `Calendar` inside of a table, but I've run into a problem when trying to get the number of days in a specific month during a specific year.

This is the bit of code I'm using:

```
    //accept input from command prompt in form of MONTH, DAY, YEAR
    String date = args[0];
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try
    {
        convertedDate = df.parse(date);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(convertedDate);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



    //get number of days in month
    int numDays, startMonth;
    numDays = cal.getActualMaximum(DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

and I'm getting an error from that last line that reads:

`error: cannot find symbol and it points to the DAY_OF_MONTH variable.`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH):

```
numDays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

It's a *static* field on the `Calendar` class.